# How to reverse a string using command line?

Tags: c, command-line

I am trying to reverse a string using command line argument but I don't know why am I getting segmentation fault for this .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *str = argv[1];
    char *rev;

    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++); {
        k = i - 1;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
        rev[j] = str[k]; 
        k--;
    }
    printf("The reverse string is %s\n", rev);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `len`?

Comment: you never initialize `char *rev;` to point at a valid memory location

Comment: You aren't allocating any storage for `rev`, and even if you were, you aren't copying the terminating `'\0'`.  Also, why did you place the initial assignment to `k` in a block?  It's very misleading, given the preceding one-line `for` loop.  And why are you using the loop?  You already have `len`, so `k` is just `len - 1`.

Comment: Because `rev` doesn't point anywhere meaningful, it's just an uninitialized pointer. Use `malloc()` or a variable-length array --- or a fixed-size array if an upper bound for string length is ok.

Comment: You need to allocate `len + 1` memory to `rev` variable.

Comment: Aside about user input: assume nothing  / check everything. In this case you have accessed `argv[1]` (through `str`) without checking `argc >= 2`.

Comment: Well, now that it's been reformatted, it's clear that you believe the first assignment to `k` is inside the preceding `for` loop.  It isn't, nor does it need to be.  The semicolon terminates the `for` loop, and the block that follows it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for reverse string and make `rev` to point to that location.

```
 char *rev = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1); // 1 extra space to store null character.
```

And terminate the reversed string at the end

```
rev[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Or just reverse the whole thing in place...

Comment: I initialized but now it doesn't print any output

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop

```
    for(j = 0; j <= i-1; j++)
    {
        rev[j] = str[k];
        k--;
    }
    //Add this line
    rev[j]='\0'; //always terminate character array with null.
    printf("The reverse string is %s\n",rev);
```

Comment: It's a good point, but `char *rev` has no memory allocated!

Comment: yeah!! We need to allocate the memory. I forgot to add it,

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- There is an extra `;` in the line `for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++); {`
- you store characters to `rev` but this pointer is uninitialized, the behavior is undefined.

You can just reverse the string in place this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
       char *str = argv[1];
       int i, j, len = strien(str);

       for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
           char c = str[i];
           str[i] = str[j];
           str[j] = c;
       }
       printf("The reverse string is %s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would `for (i = 0, j = len; i < j; i++, j--) {` make it more readable

Comment: @EdHeal: `for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {` is indeed more readable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    if ( !( argc < 2 ) )
    {
        if ( !*argv[1] )
        {
            printf("The reverse string is " ); 
        }
        else
        {
            ++argv[1];
            main( argc, argv );
            --argv[1];
            putchar( *argv[1] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```